# MySQL: How can I find out which row has the greater value?

Tags: mysql

Ultimately, I am trying to delete the duplicate row(s) and keep the row with the larger numeric data. So to find the duplicate data, I would use:

`SELECT * FROM tbl GROUP BY a HAVING COUNT(a)>1`

Now how can I find the row that has the large number in column `field_a`?

Comment: Have you tried MAX() -> http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlmax.php

Comment: That can help me isolate the MAX, but I need to delete everything other than the MAX. How can I do that?

Comment: DELETE FROM tbl WHERE MAX(a) <> 1  (the <> means not, so Where max of a is not 1) But test it first with a select before running that query

Comment: That query doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (sort of a cop-out):

```
DELETE t
FROM t
EXCEPT (max-query-on-t)
```

Also consider the case when *two* records have the same max value.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete tbl from tbl, 
(
  select a, max(field_a) as max_a
  from tbl
  group by a 
  having count(a)>1
) as max_for_a
where tbl.a=max_for_a.a and tbl.field_a!=max_for_a.max_a;
```

if you have a two or more greater value for field_a for each a, it will not able to delete all

to fix this, you would need to run another query like

```
select a, count(*) from tbl group by a;
```

and for each a

```
delete from tbl where a=? limit (total_count-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this all in one query, you need a unique key and you have to store the intermediate results in temporary tables:

```
delete from tbl where tbl.id in (select result.id from (select tbl.id from tbl join (select max(a) as a from tbl) as maxa where tbl.a<>maxa.a) as result)
```

I would advise splitting this up in two or three separate queries, though.